# How to conditionally format a Kendo UI Grid row containted inside a tabstrip?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to Kendo UI.

I'm trying to conditionally color rows inside a Kendo UI grid using Razor syntax. The grid is contained inside a Kendo UI Tabstrip. Here is the code I've written:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("Books")
                .Selected(true)
                .Content(
                @<text>@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Library.Models.Books>)ViewBag.Books)
                          .Name("grid2")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(books => books.BookID);
                              columns.Bound(books => books.BookName);
                          })
                           .ClientRowTemplate(
                              "<tr class= 'red' data-uid='#= uid #'>" +
                              "<td>#: BookID #</td>" +
                              "<td>#: BookName #</td>" +
                              "</tr>")
                          .Pageable()
                          .Sortable()
                )
                </text>
                );

        }))
```

Although, at the moment, I'm not checking for particular values, I'd like to color it based on some condition, but even this simple task of coloring row in red color isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check this post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/conditionally-changing-the-row-color

Comment: @calinaadi Thank you for your response. Yes, I've already gone through this link and a bunch of other Telerik resources. Not sure what is wrong with my code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for any future searches on the same topic.

It turns out to be that the problem was that the grid's current binding was server binding, and ClientRowTemplate() is applicable only when Ajax binding is used, hence, it wasn't getting applied at all. Changed the data source to Ajax and it worked like a charm.

I ended up opening a support ticket with Telerik and following is the response I got:

> ... Regarding the row template, the ClientRowTemplate() method is applicable only when Ajax binding is used, so in the current case it was not applied to the Grid. ...

Here is my code now with conditionally formatted row:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("Books")
                .Selected(true)
                .Content(@<text>@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Library.Models.Books>)ViewBag.Books)
                          .Name("grid2")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(books => books.BookID);
                              columns.Bound(books => books.BookName);
                          })
                          .ClientRowTemplate(                                   
                               "<tr data-uid='#= uid #'>"+
                                    "<td class='#= BookID == 1 ? \"red\" : BookID == 2 ? \"orange\" : BookID == 3 ? \"yellow\" : \"green\" #' style=\"text-align:center;\">#: BookID #</td>" +
                                     "<td>#: BookName #</td>" +
                               "</tr>"
                               )
                         .Pageable()
                         .Sortable()
                         .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                  .Ajax()
                                  .PageSize(20)
                                  .ServerOperation(false)
                          )
            )
            </text>
            );
    }))
```

In order to change the binding from server binding to Ajax, just add the following to the grid:

```
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .ServerOperation(false)
 )
```

What I was after was to conditionally format various rows/cells, based on BookID's value. Ended up applying the conditional format (applying various classes) to a 'td' tag. Same can be applied to a 'tr' tag, if the whole row needs to be conditionally formatted instead of a cell. i.e.

```
.ClientRowTemplate("<tr class='#= BookID == 1 ? \"red\" : BookID == 2 ? \"orange\" : BookID == 3 ? \"yellow\" : \"green\" #' data-uid='#= uid #'>"+
    "<td>#: BookID #</td>" +
    "<td>#: BookName #</td>" +
    "</tr>"
)
```